# PHP RegEx to get form values

Tags: php, regex, forms

If you're given a form in a string format like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="thisID" value="Text Value" />
```

How can you get the value "Text Value"? Also with:

```
<select name="thisSelect" size="1">
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two" selected>Two</option
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

How can you get the value "two" or "Two"?

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse complex HTML. Just use the DOM extension: http://www.php.net/DOM

Comment: looks promising. will post updates in a while.

Comment: the DOM extension is way too heavy to munch.

consider this example:


    $thisform = '<input type="text" value="ThisValue" name="thisID" />';
    $returnValue = getValueFromForm($thisform);


outputs:

     $returnValue == 'ThisValue';

I need to come up with the directives of the function getValueFromForm(). Any way possible?

Answer (score 0):

[edit]
I might've misunderstood the question, if so, Lèse majesté posted a very useful comment.

For the hidden input, you need to set a name to it, otherwise it will not be sent. Once you've set a name to it, you can access it in PHP using `$_POST`:

```
$postedValue = $_POST['name_of_field'];
```

You can't access the text within the This text, that text is only providing information to the user on the available options, you can only access the `value` attribute, the same way as above:

```
$postedSelect = $_POST['thisSelect'];
```

Comment: That's only when you submit the form.

one application can be when you export a table into xls format, you want to remove the form elements and remain just the text. How can you retain the values of the form elements?